# Detecting key stroke in vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How can I get an event handler to be fired whenever a user taps on any keyboard key?

I've tried in my main component:

```
<template>
  <div class="Controller" @keypress="handleKeyPressed">
```

And later on in the methods:

```
handleKeyPressed(e) {
      console.log(e)
}
```

However, when I press any key - I don't see a log in the console and it seems that no key stroke is captured by vue.js

How can I get an event handler to be fired whenever a user taps on any keyboard key?

Answer (score 2):

While some of the other answers might work for you, I've started using a composable made available from the vueuse library.

https://vueuse.org/core/usemagickeys/

```
import { useMagicKeys, whenever } from '@vueuse/core'

const keys = useMagicKeys()

whenever(keys.shift_space, () => {
  console.log('Shift+Space have been pressed')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `window.addEventListener('keypress', yourListenerCallback, options)` for listen keypress event on `created` hook and `window.removeEventListener('keypress', yourListenerCallback, options)` on `beforeDestroy` hook for remove your listener

Answer (score 1):

You may need to add the event parameter like this:

```
<div class="Controller" @keypress="handleKeyPressed($event)">
```

Answer (score 1):

As you have `non-input` element, I don't think only `@keypress` event will work for `<div>` element. To make it work you have to add `tabindex="0"`.

Live Demo **:**

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    handleKeyPressed(e) {
      console.log(e)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
   <div class="Controller" @keypress="handleKeyPressed($event)" tabindex="0">Hello Vue JS!</div>
</div>
```